# The Mantra Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

A sentence that can never fail
A broken foot without its tail
Almost there... reverse one sound
By turns mundane and quite profound.

The mantra is your compass then
Your watch to know exactly when
It dawns on you no kin or kith
Is closer than the one you’re with.